# How do I programmatically mute the iPhone or bring the volume to zero?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting iphone to vibrate and setting iphone back to sound via app.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465733/setting-iphone-to-vibrate-and-setting-iphone-back-to-sound-via-app)

I know there are other questions on this same topic, but the iPhone SDK has changed significantly since then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The answer hasn't changed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465733/setting-iphone-to-vibrate-and-setting-iphone-back-to-sound-via-app/1466904#1466904) In short, no there is not a way, and for good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's philosophy is not to let any application adjust items that should be controlled by the Settings App.  Right or wrong, if it's a system wide user preference, or a preference for another App, you have no control over it.

-t