# Silent device using CoreBluetooth framework

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am building an application for accessory on iPhone that requires to silent the iPhone. Now I know from the app itself silenting the phone is not possible as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465733/setting-iphone-to-vibrate-and-setting-iphone-back-to-sound-via-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306790/programmatically-silence-iphone-from-app) or it is possible with private apis as explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157137/using-avsystemcontroller-in-iphone-app).

Now I also read Apple bluetooth accessory guidelines for volume control and it has a profile known as [Audio/Video Remote Control Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles) which accessory can use to control the volume of the device. Also explained in [Section 2.2.5.5](https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf) **Volume Handling**

But my question is can this profile be used to silent the device?

Comment: Your peripheral would need to implement the legacy AVRCP profile and be paired with the phone in settings. You can't do this by BLE/Core Bluetooth

Comment: thank you for your response much appreciated!